# How can I list all man pages that have certain text without displaying contents?

Tags: man

I'd like to search for a certain string in all system man pages, but I only want to get a list of the man pages where this text appears.  The first 2 pages of results Google returned do not provide the answer I'm after, if at all such an answer exists.

***Let me explain:***

I'd like to see all man pages where the word `hairpin` appears.  I proceed to type `man -K hairpin`, and the contents that appear are akin to me having typed `man nmcli`.  When I exit this man page via <kbd>q</kbd>, the following then appears on my screen:

```
--Man-- next: bridge(8) [ view (return) | skip (Ctrl-D) | quit (Ctrl-C) ]
```

From here, I can continuously type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and eventually return to the command prompt with the following displayed above the prompt:

```
--Man-- next: bridge(8) [ view (return) | skip (Ctrl-D) | quit (Ctrl-C) ]
--Man-- next: lldptool-evb22(8) [ view (return) | skip (Ctrl-D) | quit (Ctrl-C) ]
--Man-- next: systemd.network(5) [ view (return) | skip (Ctrl-D) | quit (Ctrl-C) ]
--Man-- next: nm-settings(5) [ view (return) | skip (Ctrl-D) | quit (Ctrl-C) ]
--Man-- next: nm-settings-ifcfg-rh(5) [ view (return) | skip (Ctrl-D) | quit (Ctrl-C) ]
--Man-- next: systemd.directives(7) [ view (return) | skip (Ctrl-D) | quit (Ctrl-C) ]
```

What I'm asking is, is it possible to get a listing of the `man pages` where `hairpin` appears such as below?:

```
man -<some-option> -K hairpin
nmcli(1)
bridge(8)
lldptool-evb22(8)
systemd.network(5)
nm-settings(5)
nm-settings-ifcfg-rh(5)
systemd.directives(7)
```

Edit:
Searching Google using a sentence doesn't always return the results where the specific query is addressed.  This is obviously the case for this question, as pointed out by several that it is indeed a duplicate.

However, it would be best not to delete it as it shows the specific output returned on Ubuntu systems.  A user on Ubuntu may benefit from this question.

Edit 2:
Searching for `skip (Ctrl-D)` now has this question appearing in the first page of Google results where previously nothing was returned!

Comment: Is a terrible ugly hack like `PAGER="head -1" man -K hairpin </dev/null` good enough for you?

Comment: Awesome, Celada.  Now I just need to type it a few times to train the grey matter!  It would be better though if an option was added to `man` to allow for this.

Comment: A better version of @Celada's clever trick could be `PAGER='awk "NR==1{print $1}"' man -K hairpin </dev/null` or even `PAGER='perl -lane "print lc($F[0]) if $.==1"' man -K hairpin </dev/null`. Celada, why not whip that into an answer?

Comment: @terdon, I don't think other answers will get votes being that the answer you've provided indicates that this option already exists - just that I wasn't aware - or rather, hadn't taken the time to read the manual thoroughly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `-w` option:

```
   -w, --where, --path, --location
          Don't actually display the manual pages, but do print the  loca‐
          tion(s) of the source nroff files that would be formatted.
```

That returns almost what you asked for:

```
$ man -wK hairpin
/usr/share/man/man1/nmcli.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/ip-link.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/bridge.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/systemd.network.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/nm-settings.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/nm-settings-ifcfg-rh.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man7/systemd.directives.7.gz
```

If that's not enough, you can parse it into shape:

```
$ man -wK hairpin | perl -pe 's#.*/([^/]+)\.(\d+)\.gz#$1($2)#'
nmcli(1)
ip-link(8)
bridge(8)
systemd.network(5)
nm-settings(5)
nm-settings-ifcfg-rh(5)
systemd.directives(7)
```

Finally, you could make that into a function. Add this line to your shell's initialization file (`~/.bashrc`, for example):

```
function sman(){ man -wK "$@" | perl -pe 's#.*/([^/]+)\.(\d+)\.gz#$1($2)#'; }
```

Then, you can run:

```
$ sman hairpin
nmcli(1)
ip-link(8)
bridge(8)
systemd.network(5)
nm-settings(5)
nm-settings-ifcfg-rh(5)
systemd.directives(7)
```